# Does anybody have a CSS template to connect Twitter Bootstrap with one of the color scheme designers?

Tags: css, color-scheme, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to take the output from http://colorschemedesigner.com/ and connect it to my Twitter Bootstrap code. I know how to do this the old-fashioned way. What I'm looking for is a better way - a script or CSS template that can take the color values and plug them into CSS such that they are cascaded appropriately and ubiquitously. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork bootstrap-sass and make all changes in this file : https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/variables.scss

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try. Thanks.